# Initialising a map is giving following error

Tags: c++

I am trying to initialize map in the following way, but I'm not able to do so.
Could you please give me a suggestion?

```
map<char , int> err_codes = {{'a',1},{'b',0}};
```

> ERROR : initialization with '{...}' is not allowed for object of type
>   "std::map, std::allocator>>"

Comment: C is not a relevant tag to this question...

Comment: Please copy and paste error messages instead of paraphrasing.

Comment: I don't think you can initialize an object of the given type by using that syntax. Except if you request the c++11 standard.

Comment: I voted to close as a duplicate. The other question is about `vector`, but the answer and the problem is the same. You can do uniform initialization  only if your compiler supports c++11.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems your compiler does not support this C++ 2011 feature of list initializations for standard containers. Check the compiler documentation how to switch on the support of C++ 2011 if it is possible.

Comment: I think this is it, but it seems that the compiler is gcc so pobably `-std=c++11` would do it.